# Paths wordpress is listening on

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day everyone!

I got a site on wordpress and I want to disable any possible URLs to access/post info on it except some legal. I printed `$wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules()` (or something like that, I got no code now to point at exactly) and see many paths which are accessible from outside.

Are there any other ways to determine *all* paths available on my site? Maybe there's a nice tool to use or doc about that?

Comment: maybe you can check the sitemap

Answer (score 0):

There is no rewrite table in Wordpress like you might see in other CMS platfroms. The rewrite URLs are generated dynamically based on your permalink settings and the slug/meta for a given post. If you are trying to find a list of the URLs you should probably try a [sitemap generating plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/) before writing something yourself.

If you are trying to find a list of the rules that Wordpress is using you can simply use the [`rewrite_rules_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array) filter like so:

```
function dump_rewrites($rules){
    print_r($rules);
    exit;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'dump_rewrites');
```

This will exit the PHP process and print the rules on the webpage.